# C: Why do strings seem to be recognized when taken from command line than when it was set within the program?

Tags: c, string, command-line-arguments

For example:
Let's say I manually put in:

```
char * string = "\n\n";
```

When I call `strlen(string)`, I will rightfully get `2`.

HOWEVER, if I got string from the command-line, I would get a value of `4` for `strlen(string)` instead.

Why is that and how do I fix this problem so that I would get `2` instead of `4`?

Also when I tried to print out the command-line argument, I got `"\n\n"` rather than two skipped lines.

How do I change that?

Comment: Because your shell does not seem to escape `\n\n`. It passes the literal string `\n\n` to your program instead of two newlines.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but shell usage.

Comment: How are you reading your input, do you use getch, gets, fprintf?

Answer (score 2):

When o insert \n\n via command line, the caracteres read are '\','n','\','n', so 4 for size is right. When you put \n\n in a string constant like you did you are putting the special caracter '\n' in your string so the size for "\n\n" is actually 2.

If you wanted to put a '\n' in a string you would have to right "\\n" instead of "\n".

Also, note that, you cannot write "`\n\n`" to your command line and expect the parser to interpret it as line breaks, if you want to pass a text to your program with lots of text with `\n`,`\t` etc... you should consider writing that in a file and then call your program like this 
`.\prog.out < sample.txt` to redirect the content of the file as input to the stdin.

After that you should consider using strtok to parse your input, strtok splits strings into tokens, read more [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/strtok.html).

Answer (score 0):

"\n" is a is a representation for a new line character in code in C. In pascal it would be #10. So quick way would be to replace all "\n"s in the string with '\n's .

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *repnl(char *str){
    char *from, *to;
    from = to = str;
    while(*from){
        if(*from == '\\' && from[1] == 'n'){
            *to++ = '\n';
            from += 2;
         } else
            *to++ = *from++;
    }
    *to = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    repnl(argv[1]);
    printf("len=%d\n", strlen(argv[1])); 
    return 0;
}
```